# Can I add exception page while redirecting the user

Tags: .net, vb.net, redirect

I am on .net framework with vb language. I am making use of request.urlReferrer in my login page like this in page_load

> Session("PreviousPage") = Request.UrlReferrer

I redirected the user like this when I click the login button.

```
If Not Session("PreviousPage") Is Nothing Then
Response.Redirect(Session("PreviousPage").ToString)
End If
```

The problem is when my previous page is login page. I am logged in to the system but redirected again to the login page. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you redirecting the value from Request.UrlReferrer

Comment: Heya, and welcome to stack overflow. To make it easier to get good answers to your question you should try to make sure to only ask one question in each question. If there are two then there may end up being confusion and conflict between the two. Also your title doesn't seem to reflect either of your questions since I don't quite see where the exception page comes into this question...

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes.  First you need to find out what distinguishes your login page from any non-login page.  Maybe it is the presence of a particular control (called `Login1` in the following example):

```
Dim LoginControl As Control
LoginControl = PreviousPage.FindControl("Login1")
If Not LoginControl Is Nothing Then
    ... handle exception here ...
Else
    Response.Redirect(Session("PreviousPage").ToString)
End If
```

Or maybe it is its URL in which case you can use [`HttpWebRequest.Referer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) to detect it.  Referer is the same thing as the previous page, in case of HTTP and normal browsing behavior.

Comment: I got this error  
" System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " here
" LoginControl = CType(PreviousPage.FindControl("Login1"), Login) "

Comment: @user1498364 - Actually the cast was just superfluous in this context.  Removed.